# Django static assets reference in Jinja Templates

Tags: html, django, web, macros, jinja2

I have a Jinja macro defined as follows.

**globalmacros.html**

```
{% macro SUINavMenu(leftlist=[],logo="images/Logo_WEB_450_250.png") %}
 <div class="ui pointing secondary menu">
  <div class="item">
  <img src="{{ static({{ logo }}) }}"> 
 </div>
 {% for item in leftlist %}
  <a class="item" href="{{ item[1] }}">
   {{ item[0] }}
  </a>
 {% endfor %}
 </div>
{% endmacro %}
```

**dashboard.html**

```
{% from "macros/globalmacros.html" import SUINavMenu %}
{% block navigation %}
{{  SUINavenu(leftlist=[["Home","/home/"],["New Bill","/newbill/"]],
    logo="images/web_logo.png") }}
{% endblock navigation %}
```

I am importing the macro defined in "globalmacros.html" into "dashboard.html" and trying to pass the logo location. However I am not sure *how* to do it.

In a non-macro version, the following code works.

```
<img src=" {{ static('images/logo_web.png') }} "></img>
```

The above code in "globalmacros.html" doesnt work as Jinja does not process an {{}} inside another {{}}

What is the work around for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've strong supposition that `<img src="{{ static(logo) }}">` should work. If it doesn't I would report this as a bug.

Comment: I got this error. Exception Type:TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value: expected token ':', got '}'

Comment: So... for me it looks like implementation is screwed up because it makes no god damn sense for me.

Comment: Sorry. It worked. That's the way to do it. Thank you very much. The error I mentioned above was due to an unrelated issue.

Comment: Can you please provide the unrelated issue as I am getting the same error.